# Zxing:Activity get Result

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, zxing

I've making my own app, with a menu and in one activity iam trying to get the result of a qrcode.
I need to get the IntentResult but how? And where I get the onActivityResult working?
Its a litle confuse, this via intent.

How can I implement a function to get the text to a string?

Truly thankful.
RMC

Activity:

```
public class Authentication extends Activity {

  TextView showResults;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Load file xml
    setContentView(R.layout.authentication);

    //To create start button
    Button scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartAuth);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {         
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(Authentication.this);
        integrator.initiateScan();
      }
    });


    //HERE I NEED TO GET THE VALUE OF THE QR CODE WITH MY ONACTIVITYRESULT 
    // BUT WHERE I GET THE
    //PROTOTYPE VALUES?
  } //end_of_onCreate


  // functions
  public void getResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        EditText showResults = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtviewResultados);
        showResults.setText(contents);
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // Every time I receive this code
        showResults.setText("Error reading: result null");
      }
    }
  } 
}//end_of_activity
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You are already getting the text of the barcode:

```
    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
```

If you are trying to use `IntentIntegrator`, and `IntentResult`, what is all this code? looks like you are duplicating what they do, but probably incorrectly -- don't know since I don't know what you are trying to do exactly.

Just use `IntentIntegrator` to *also* parse the result.